# How to store columns of an array into different variables using python?

Tags: python

I am new to python. And I am trying to store columns of an array into different variables. The size of the array which I have is 40x100 and I want to store these 100 columns into 100 variables. Which I will then use to plot and fit them.

I tried using the following code, but it stores all the columns in one variable

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.genfromtxt('PE1889_0__old.txt', skip_header=9) #imports data from file and stores in data
sp= data[:4000,0]
Y = data[:4000,5]
plt.plot(sp,Y)
plt.xlabel("Scan path [mm]")
plt.ylabel("Y [mm]")
X=np.reshape(sp,(40,100)) #reshapes sp into a 40x100 matrix
print(len(X[0,:]))
X_col = (len(X[:,0]))
d={}
for i in range(X_col):
  d["col{0}".format(i)]=(X[:,i])
```

Comment: paste the contents of your PE1889_0__old.txt here, or at least parts of it so we know what it contains

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of rows, and you want to get a list of columns instead, you can use the `zip` built-in function

```
rows = [ # list of 40 rows, each with 100 values
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6 ,7, ...., 100],
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6 ,7, ...., 100],
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6 ,7, ...., 100],
    .
    .
    .
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6 ,7, ...., 100],  # 40th row in this list, containing 100 values
]

columns = list(zip(*data))

print(columns)
```

Output

```
[ # list of 100 columns, each with 40 values
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1],
   .
   .
   .,
   [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, ..., 100], # 100th column, containing 40 values
]
```

Comment: I can send you the PE1889_0__old.txt file. But I do not want change rows and columns, I want to get each column with 40 rows in a seperate variable.